# Apps Script web app accessing Google Spreadsheets gets "#VALUE!" on every cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a Google Spreadsheets with a couple of sheets that get data from other spreadsheets via IMPORTRANGE function and then calculate numeric values based on that data. Then, I assembled a code snippet as web app to retrieve the first sheet of the spreadsheet and show it as a flex table.

Besides the `doGet` function, I added a "refresher" to retrieve the data from the spreadsheet, because when the spreadsheet is closed, no calculations are performed, and the script would only read empty cells.

However, even though the "refresher" is in place, it shows only `#VALUE!` where the numbers should display.

```
    function doGet(){
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  var flexTable = app.createFlexTable().setStyleAttribute('border', '3px solid MidnightBlue')
      .setStyleAttribute('borderCollapse','collapse')
      .setBorderWidth(2);
      //Get Data from spreadsheet
  var spreadsheetId = 'xxxx.xxx.xxxx';
  var dataArray = getData(spreadsheetId);
 //Load data into table cells 
  for (var row = 0; row<dataArray.length; row++){
    for (var col = 0; col<dataArray[row].length; col++){
      flexTable.setText(row, col, dataArray[row][col].toString());
    }
  }  
  panel.add(flexTable);
  app.add(panel);
  return app;
}

function refreshSheet(spreadsheetId, sheet) {
  var spreadsheetId = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx');
  var sheet = spreadsheetId.getSheetByName('Sheet_to_Display');
  var dataArrayRange = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),sheet.getLastColumn());
  var dataArray = dataArrayRange.getValues(); // necessary to refresh custom functions
  var notValueFound = true;
  while(notValueFound) {
    for(var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
      if(dataArray[i].indexOf('#VALUE!') >= 0) {
        notValueFound = true;
        dataArray = dataArrayRange.getValues();
        break;
      } // end if
      else if(i == dataArray.length - 1) notValueFound = false;
    } // end for
  } // end while
}

function getData (spreadsheetId){
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0].getDataRange();
  return sheet.getValues();
}
```

I'm adding an actual screenshot to further illustrate the issue. The alphanumeric values that appear are "native" to the spreadsheet, and the values that do not, are coming from other spreadsheet via IMPORTRANGE function. The script is placed in the "google site root", not inside the spreadsheet.

[image: Screenshot]

I'm not sure where to fix my code, please give me a hint!

Comment: Try `flexTable.setWidget(row, col, app.createTextBox().setText(dataArray[row][col].toString()));`. Btw, I don't see how your code can build a flex table like this. Welcome to Web Applications Gabriel !!

Comment: How is the `refreshSheet` function invoked, with a button, trigger?

Comment: **@JacobJanTuinstra**: Thanks for the welcoming! I tried `flexTable.setWidget(row, col, app.createTextBox().setText(dataArray[row][col].toString()));` and it makes the columns with a fixed width, and there are just too many to fit the webpage. However, the style is neat and very html-stylish. Is there a way to tell the flextable to adjust the width to the extent of the text only?

Comment: **@JacobJanTuinstra**: I'm setting a 1-hour trigger to the function  `refreshSheet` to test it's behaviour... Thanks for asking that!

Comment: I've learned something today Gabriel: `flexTable.setText(row, col, data.toString());` will create a flex table !!

Comment: The code seems to be working fine. I added a time-based trigger (1 by the hour) to invoke the refreshSheet function, suggested by **@JacobJanTuinstra**, and it works like charm. However, I may have 300+ versions of this code retrieving data from 300+ spreadsheets inserted in 300+ Google Sites pages, under the same domain in Google Apps, and I believe I might encounter some usage limits. Don't you think? Any ideas?

Comment: Great **@JacobJanTuinstra**! Glad you found it useful to create tables with `flexTable.setText(row, col, data.toString());`. Is it possible to combine it with `flexTable.setWidget(row, col, app.createTextBox().setText(dataArray[row][col].toString()));` to create styled borders, but bound in width to the text lenght?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the [Class UiApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/ui-app) used by the OP script is deprecated.